# How to implement a browser extension that adds a sidebar to each web page?

Tags: sidebar, browser-extension, kango-framework

All

I am using http://kangoextensions.com/ to create an extension for multiple browsers.

This extension needs to add a sidebar to each webpage in each tab, that allows the user to interact with my server from the web page.

What I currently have is a content script that adds an iframe to the webpage. The iframe is initially hidden, but when the user presses a button I also added, the iframe is shown.
The iframe source is my own website.

This works great for the most part, but I have an issue - when the user is constantly navigating between pages, my iframe constantly disappears and re-appears with each navigation, which is not a great user experience.

I also tried using a browser extension popup window, but this window disappears when it loses focus, so it does not fit my use case.

I am looking for a way to have a "proper" sidebar - a window that is loaded once and lives for the entire duration of the browser tab.

If anyone knows of a way to achieve this, I would really appreciate it. Ideally - a solution that works on all browsers, but if you know of a way that will work only on some browsers, that's good too.

Thanks
Amir

Answer (score 0):

Kango does not support sidebars at the moment.
The best you can manage is a popup.